# Docker container starting issue: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, vps, cgroups, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm a little newbie to Docker. I was trying to deploying Hortonworks sandbox on docker but unfortunately, the below error encountered.

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused:
> process_linux.go:545: container init caused: process_linux.go:508:
> setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused: resulting devices
> cgroup doesn't match target mode: unknown.

Once I was able to set up everything on a different server correctly which was a Ubuntu 20.04 VPS from Contabo.

**But this time I have used a VPS from VPSDime and I have tested this on 3 different operating systems and the same error occurred: Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 18.04, CentOS 8.**

Please help me, I have followed this guide here: https://tomas-savenas.medium.com/hortonworks-sandbox-hdp-3-0-on-ubuntu-18-04-using-docker-da579fd654f9

Comment: The error looks similar to the one mentioned here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/onui0l/docker_not_working_after_latest_update/. You might try downgrading `containerd.io` to 1.4.6

Answer (score 3):

i had pretty much the same error message with Arch Linux using the old Linux-CK kernel with MuQSS. in my case MuQSS was the rootcause for this error, but I could make it work with the following workaround.
Add this line to the kernel parameters:

```
systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0
```

source: [Fix Docker cgroup errors after systemd 248 update](https://my-take-on.tech/2021/05/07/fix-docker-cgroup-errors-after-systemd-248-update/)